# How to allow empty or numeric values in codeigniter's form_validation class?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I'd like to have input validated with form_validation class, that'll allow me to put numeric or empty value in the field.
Something like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('field[]','The field','numeric or empty|xss_clean');
```

Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 8):

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('field[]', 'The field', 'numeric|xss_clean');
```

This should be sufficient in theory, since the field hasn't been set to required.

Comment: But, it returns me the errors. Might it be an Codeigniter's bug? I'm using 2.0.3

Answer (score 3):

> But, it returns me the errors

Then perhaps an extra step:

```
if (!empty($this->input->post('field[]')))
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('field[]', 'The field', 'numeric|xss_clean');
}
```

Comment: @sunpietro -- Have you had a chance to test it out yet?

Answer (score 1):

For phone number with 10 digits:

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'Mobile Number ', 'required|regex_match[/^[0-9]{10}$/]'); //{10} for 10 digits number
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean  "**Using Arrays as Field Names**"

You can have a look at [this page](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#theform)

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('field[]','The field','is_natural|trim|xss_clean');
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $errors = $this->form_validation->error_array();
        if (!empty($errors['field'])) {
            $errors_data = $errors['field'];
        }
        print_r($errors_data);exit;
    }
```

You can use ***is_natural*** that Returns FALSE if the form element contains anything other than a natural number: 0, 1, 2, 3, etc.
For empty checking ***required*** rule is used that Returns FALSE if the form element is empty. So remove the required rule is if used.
And use ***form_validation*** rules for showing your rules message